# adding a field to subclass in python

Tags: python, subclass

I have a base class

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def title(self):
        return self.name+str(self.age)
```

I need to subclass this to get an Employee class where an empid is also an attribute

```
class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs,empid):
        Person.__init__(self, *args)
        self.empid= empid
    def title(self):
        return self.name+str(self.age)+self.empid
```

For example , suppose Jon is an Employee with empid="001"

```
j = Employee('Jon',30,'001')
print j.title()
```

should give `Jon30001`

I am getting a syntax error..Am I doing the subclassing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional arguments must come last in a method signature. There is also an indentation problem in your original post, but it looks like it was a copy/paste error while posting. The following should work better for you.

[EDIT]

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def title(self):
        return self.name+str(self.age)

class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        Person.__init__(self, *args)
        self.empid= kwargs.get('empid')
    def title(self):
        return self.name+str(self.age)+self.empid
```

output ->

```
>>> j = Employee('Jon',30,empid="001")
>>> j.title()
'Jon30001'
```

Comment: It feels more correct  to call `p=Employee('Jon',30,'001')` ,but then it will not work as expected